# How to display photos like iphone homescreen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, swap, homescreen

I'm trying to make an app that's displaying my photos from camera roll like app icons in iphone (matrix view) . The pictures will have the "wobble" effect and the pictures need to be rearrangeable(the posibility to swap pictures).

I found out how to implement the wobble efect.

What`s the best way to implement the displaying and swapping functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to show your photos using CALayer.
Add those layer in Matrix like pattern in your UIView using frame property of layer.

To move or rearrange photos find particular CALayer in touchesBegin method of View using touch points and Move it with movement in touched(in touchesMoved). Settle it in a proper location in touchesEnded method.

I have assumed that you have basic knowledge of usage of classes that I mentioned in above description.

Post here if you need more help.

Comment: I`m new to iOs development, so, I appreciate if you could tell me some tutorial for using CALayer.

Comment: Have a look at this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CALayer and after that read sample code provided by apple in CALayer class reference.